# QWebView and IPv6 link local

Tags: qt, ipv6, qwebview

I'm trying to use the QWebView of the Qt 5.1 framework with IPv6 : it works fine with global scope IPv6 address, but I can not open link local address such as  `http://[fe80::210:f3ff:fe29:a5f4%eth0]`.

Is it a limitation ?

Regards.

Comment: I have yet to find any web application which understands the scope of a Link-Local address.

Comment: WebKit is known to be unable to handle link-local IPv6 address literals.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your feedback.